# Why Signature-Level-Protection is not working for my Android service?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-security

I have an App1 which uses services of App2 (AIDL). Now I want signature level protection for the service in App2. Here is my manifest.

App2: Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.vinitanilgaikwad.android_additionservice">

<permission
    android:name="com.example.vinitanilgaikwad.android_additionservice.SIGNATURE"
    android:description="@string/permissionDesc"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/permissionLabel"
    android:permissionGroup="com.example.vinitanilgaikwad.android_additionservice.SIGNATURE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".AdditionService2"

        android:permission="com.example.vinitanilgaikwad.android_additionservice.SIGNATURE"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="service.Calculator"
                 />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>

</manifest>
```

However, this is not working as my service is accessible even though App1 is not signed by the same keystore. Could you please help?

Comment: Fully uninstall and reinstall App1, and see if the problem clears up.

Comment: Same problem @CommonsWare

Comment: Does App1 have a `<permission>` element in its manifest that has `android:name="com.example.vinitanilgaikwad.android_additionservice.SIGNATURE"`? If so, edit your question to include App1's manifest.

Comment: @VinitGaikwad Is this issue resolved?

Comment: At one computer, By default each app get signed with same key(system debug key) while build generation. Hence app1 and app2 are signed with same key, so app2 service  is accessible by app1. Try to use two different key store for each while generating build.